# How to think about muscle fatigue?

Tags: recovery

I'm trying to figure out how to think about Fatigue. A simple model one can start with is that if a muscle is used more, then it's fatigued more. However, suppose one is on leg day and is at the end of a set of heavy 5x5 squats, if they train bench afterwards, then it'd be with subpar performance.

I've noticed also, that on day after subsequent to  heavy squats, my bench suffers. Perhaps it could just be lack of effective leg drive, but I am not ruling out the possibility that maybe that there is some other element of general level of fatigue accumulated which doesn't restore in one day.

Could someone shed light on this and perhaps suggest some resources to read as well?

Is Fatigue, in general, existing locally for certain muscle groups, or is there some general level of fatigues that occurs even if we work out different muscle groups everyday?

Comment: There hasn't been a good quantifier for fatigue yet., One of the better ones that I've seen is the Training Stress Score (TSS) by training peaks, it's geared toward triathlon type sports but that's about the only decent one I know of.